# select and image form the string of images and place it to the correct time close and open

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to create a string of images because those two images will be shared frequently but it only shows the url not the image. ti will be using the time telling for different things in the same page. But my question is. am i placing the string name correctly?
timeDiv4.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '
' + imgArray[0\1].src  ;
or do i need any else

```js
//////////////////End Modal 3////////////
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image(100,100);
imgArray[0].src = 'http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/599346900698327146/files/Gifs/OpenLightOff.png';

imgArray[1] = new Image(100,100);
imgArray[1].src = 'http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/599346900698327146/files/Gifs/OpenLightOn.gif';


var now = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";     
weekday[1] = "Monday";     
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";     
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";   
weekday[4] = "Thursday";   
weekday[5] = "Friday";      
weekday[6] = "Saturday";     

//////////Highlights the date/////

//10:00 am - 10:00 pm  
//10:00 am - 10:00 pm
//10:00 am - 10:00 pm
//10:00 am - 10:00 pm
//10:00 am - 10:00 pm
//10:00 am - 10:00 pm
//10:00 am - 10:00 pm

var checkTime4 = function() {
  var today = weekday[now.getDay()];
  var timeDiv4 = document.getElementById('timeDiv4');
  var timeBorder4 = document.getElementById('timeBorder4');

  
  var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();

  //add AM or PM
  var suffix = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
  

  // add 0 to one digit minutes
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes
  };

  if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 1 || dayOfWeek == 2 || dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 ) && hour >= 10 && hour <= 21) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
 timeDiv4.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + imgArray[1].src  ;
    timeDiv4.className = 'open';
 timeBorder4.className = 'OpenGreen';

  } 
  
  else if ((dayOfWeek == 5 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 10 && hour <= 22) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
    timeDiv4.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + imgArray[1].src  ;
    timeDiv4.className = 'open';
 timeBorder4.className = 'OpenGreen';

  } 
  
  else {
    if (hour == 0 || hour > 9) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    }
    timeDiv4.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<br>' + imgArray[0].src  ;
    timeDiv4.className = 'closed';
 timeBorder4.className = 'ClosedRed';

  }
};

setInterval(checkTime4, 1000);
checkTime4();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timeDiv4"></div>
```

Comment: You need to put the `imgArray.src` inside an image tag

Comment: '<br>' + '<br><center><img style="width:150px;top:0px;border-radius:10px;" src="'+imgArray[0].src+'" /></center>'  i tried it earlier but i replace img.src for it. i had no luck but thanks. must have type something wrong. but for the reassurance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the HTML mark up - something like this:

```
timeDiv4.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + '<img src = ' + imgArray[1].src + '>'  ;
```